# Possible to save a filter in the Chrome console?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, adblock

I have an adblocker installed, which means that whenever I open up Chrome's console I'm greeted by dozens of `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` entries.

I can filter them out with something like `^((?!net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT).)+$`, but filters are not persisted, so I have to do this constantly.

Is there a more permanent solution available, such as saving console filters or maybe a config/preference that can be edited?

Answer (score 2):

You can filter them by checking "Hide network messages". You will be able to see responses in the Network tab still. I'm not aware of any built in features to save specifc filters unfortunately.

[image: Hide network messages]

In many cases, you can hide/modify logs and errors by re-defining the [Console API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference) functions using Snippets. However, in this case, the error is not logged from the page itself, so it won't help.